# Strange behaviour of STM32 EVAL board power supply

Tags: debugging, stm32

I've been using a STM32H753I-EVAL2 board for several months now.

Last week I was suddenly not able to connect to the board anymore (tried with several tools: GDB, STM32cubeProgrammer, always same message like "STLink error"). I of course checked the driver was correctly installed and was the right one, reinstalled it, changed USB cable and ports. Also tried to connect to a Nucleo which was fine.

I randomly tried to change the power supply of the board from PSU (ie. powering through external power supply) to STLink (powering through USB) and it solved the issue. I was happy as I thought it was just a hardware issue like a conflict between both power supplies.

But today the board was not connecting anymore again. So I switched back the alim to PSU and it worked !

Did someone experience the same issue ? Or does it trigger something for someone ?

Comment: I have a feeling that this might yield more results on [https://electronics.stackexchange.com/](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Message to administrators: is it possible to move a message from one SO group to another ?